# View environment variables in gunicorn linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flask, gunicorn

I have a project that is deployed by a previous dev on a linux server. The environment variables are stored in `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`. The file doesn't seem to be present anywhere in the server but still the code runs fine. There are multiple steps to get this file set up but none to read it. I need the information to get it running on my local machine. Any cli commands to read the same?
The directory is in format:

```
app.py
requirements.txt
README.md
```

The `app.py` is the main function and the rest 2 also don't have anything to do woth gunicorn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
```